# Using of if-else in Cypress test

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, cypress

Just learning how to write conditional tests using JS in Cypress. Write sample test as per Cypress.io

**Test I trying to run:**

```
describe ('sample tests', () => {
    it('conditional test', () => {
        cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions');
        if (cy.get('input[placeholder*="Email"]')) => {
            cy.type('email-1@mail.com')
        } else {
                cy.visit('https://www.google.com/')
            }
    })
})
```

**Displayed error:**

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/e2e/4-home-page/test4.cy.js
Module build failed (from C:/Users/userName/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/12.3.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Cypressinstall\cypress\e2e\4-home-page\test4.cy.js: Unexpected token (7:51)

   5 |     it('conditional test', () => {
   6 |         cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions');
>  7 |         if (cy.get('input[placeholder*="Email"]')) => {
     |                                                    ^
   8 |             cy.type('email-1@mail.com')
   9 |         } else {
  10 |                 cy.visit('https://www.google.com/')
```

**What I tried:**
I moved "=>" in different location but Cypress display that "No tests found".

**Expected behavior:**
Cypress must run test without error, using condition if-else.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you, the purpose in your given example is to verify if the element (email field) exists and if so, type there a value. In this case you'd better use conditional testing the following way and verify if the field is visible:

```
const emailField = 'input[placeholder*="Email"]';
cy.get('body').then(($email) => {
    if ($email(emailField).is(':visible')) {
      cy.type('email-1@mail.com')
    }
    else {
     // Anything to do here
    }
  });
```

Or you can just check that element exist (if it's hidden for any reason):

```
const emailField = 'input[placeholder*="Email"]';
cy.get('body').then(($parent) => {
    if ($parent.find(emailField).length > 0) {
      cy.type('email-1@mail.com')
    }
    else {
     // Anything to do here
    }
  });
```

Instead of cy.get('body').then... you can use any DOM element which is higher in the hierarchy than your desired element.

Comment: What mean "length > 0"? That element is available?

Answer (score -1):

Understanding the use of "=>" is essential here and it has nothing to do with cypress.

The "=>" belongs to [Javascript arrow functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)

This is used to introduce shorter functions.

Now let's understand the then() method, reading this [document](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-we-use-then-method-in-javascript/)

With the above, you should be able to understand how to use these principles correctly.

More to note:

1. If an element doesn't exist conditionally, we cannot use cy.get for that element (will trigger No Such Element Exception). Use

   ```
    cy.get("body).then($body => {
      //cy.get("body") returns the dom element which we can capture 
      with "then"
      //Check if element exists
      if($body.find("input[placeholder*=\"Email\"]").length > 0){
        cy.get("input[placeholder*=\"Email\"]").type("email-1@mail.com");
      }
      else{
         cy.visit('https://www.google.com/')
      }
   })
   ```

To learn more on cypress if conditions read the [Cypress Documentations](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain why this answer was marked not helpful?